# Distance to a closed set. Is this result known?

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

Given a closed set $\varnothing\neq E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, let $\operatorname{Unp}(E)$ be the set if points $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for which there is a unique point $y\in E$ nearest to $x$.
Clearly $E\subset\operatorname{Unp}(E)$.
On the other hand, it is known that the Lebesgue measure of the set $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\operatorname{Unp}(E)$ equals zero, $\lvert\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\operatorname{Unp}(E)\rvert=0$ (cf. [Set of points with a unique closest point in a compact set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342308/121665)).

Erdős [1] proved a much stronger result:

> *The set $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\operatorname{Unp}(E)$ is contained in the sum of countably many surfaces of finite $(n-1)$-dimensional measure.*

This is a beautiful and I think, not very well known theorem.
However, from the results existing in the literature one can conclude:

> **Theorem.**
> For any closed set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$
> there are countably many $C^2$-graphs $\{ G_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ such that
> $$
> \mathcal{H}^{n-1}\Bigl((\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\operatorname{Unp}(E))\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty G_j\Bigr)=0.
> $$

Here $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ stands for the Hausdorff measure and
by a $C^2$-graph I mean the graph of a $C^2$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}$.
$$
\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mathrel: x_i=f(x_1,\dotsc,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dotsc,x_n)\}. 
$$

While the theorem can be concluded from what is in the literature, I was not able to find a straightforward reference to this statement. I think this result is of considerable interest, but most of people who would find it interesting would have difficulty to find it in the literature.

> **Question.** Do you know if this result (or something very similar) has been published anywhere?

**[1] P. Erdős**, [On the Hausdorff dimension of some sets in Euclidean space](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1946-08514-6).
*Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* 52 (1946), 107-109.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thank you. A correction has been made.

Comment: Possibly [Luděk Zajíček's work involving delta-convex mappings](https://www.google.com/search?q=Zajicek+delta-convex+%22nearest+point%22) contains this result (see also [this less restrictive search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Zajicek+delta-convex) and [this search involving cone porous sets](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cone+porous%22+%22metric+projection%22)), but much of it involves intricate technicalities and is devoted to infinite dimensional settings, neither of which I know much about.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thank you. That was helpful. Indeed, when I said  that it can be concluded from the existing results, one of them was to  Luděk Zajíček. I agree, almost everything is written in Banach spaces which is not helpful.

Comment: Incidentally, [*Pointwise bounded approximation and hypodirichlet algebras*](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1971-77-01/S0002-9904-1971-12635-6/) by Theodore William Gamelin and John Brady Garnett [**Bull. AMS** 77 #1, January 1971, pp. 137-141 (online data has incorrect last page value)] defines the following unusual (to me, at least) $\sigma$-ideal on p. 138: *A* ***curvilinear null set*** *is a subset of zero outer length lying on a twice continuously differentiable curve. A* $\sigma$-***curvilinear null set*** *is a countable union of curvilinear null sets.*

Comment: What does the term 'surface' mean in Erdos' result? Does it follow from his argument that $\mathbf{R}^n \setminus \mathrm{Unp(E)}$ is countably rectifiable?

Comment: @LeoMoos He does not say it explicitly, but I think that follows from the proof. He is using a "well known lemma" that nobody knows these days. The lemma has a vague statement about regularity of surfaces, but the proof in amazing Saks' Theory of the integral says that the surfaces are graphs of Lipschitz functions.

Answer (score 4):

I used such results in my thesis on the topology of singularities arising in various optimal transport programs (Sections 4.2-3). Especially useful was the following article of G. Alberti:

Alberti, Giovanni. "On the structure of singular sets of convex functions." Calculus of Variations and Partial Differential Equations 2.1 (1994): 17-27.

**Alberti's Theorem:** *If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is proper lower semicontinuous convex function, then the subsets $$S^k(f):=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n ~|~\dim_{\mathscr{H}} \partial_{\bullet} f \geq k\}$$ can be covered by countably many $(n-k)$-dimensional DC-manifolds.*

Here $\partial_{\bullet} f $ is the local subdifferential of $f$.

The assumption that the function $f$ is *convex* is not as restrictive as it appears, for we can always replace $f$ with a *locally semiconvex* function. See Proposition 4.3.4. in my thesis for details. And if the closed set $E$ is locally compact (of course it is), then $dist_E$ becomes locally semiconvex, and we can apply Alberti's theorem to conclude that indeed the medial axis (or $\mathbb{R}^n-Unp(E)$ in the OP's notation) has Hausdorff dimension $\leq n-1$ and can be covered by countably many $(n-1)$-dimensional $DC$-manifolds.

Related results occur in R.J.McCann's and J. Kitagawa's article "Free Discontinuities in Optimal Transport".
https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04152

Answer (score 2):

The following result can be found in

D. H. Fremlin, Skeletons and central sets, Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 74 (1997), 701–720.

Let  $\Omega$ be an open proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n > 1$. Its skeleton  is

$$R:=\{ x \in  \Omega: \text{ there are distinct } y, y'\in  \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega
 \text{ such that }
\rho( x , y ) =\rho( x , y ) = \rho( x , \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega)\},$$
where we write $\rho$ for the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Theorem 1G: Let  $\Omega$ be an open proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then its skeleton $R$ is the
union of a sequence of closed sets each of which is Lipschitz isomorphic to a subset
of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Consequently , the dimension of $R$ is at most $n-1$, whether we mean
inductive dimension , covering dimension , Hausdorff dimension or Minkowski
dimension.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Clearly, Fremlin was not aware of the work of Erdos.