# Signed distance function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, hausdorff-measure, euclidean-domain

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open and bounded set with uniform Lipschitz boundary. Consider the signed distance function:

$d:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R},\ d(x)=\begin{cases} \mathrm{dist}(x,\partial\Omega),\ x\notin\Omega \\ 0,\ x\in\partial\Omega \\ -\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial\Omega),\ x\in\Omega\end{cases}$

It is well-known that $d$ is almost everywhere differentiable (being 1-Lipschitz) and $|\nabla d(x)|\leq 1$. Also it is known that $|\nabla d(x)|=1$ in a neighbourhood of $\partial\Omega$ if $\Omega$ has a $C^2$ boundary (see *Gilbard&Trudinger*, page 355). Of course we know that $\partial\Omega$ is a compact set with finite perimeter and with null Lebesgue measure.

**My question is the following: Is it true that the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N\ |\ \exists y_1\neq y_2\in\partial\Omega\ \text{with}\  d(x)=|x-y_1|=|x-y_2|, x\notin\Omega \ \text{and} \ d(x)=-|x-y_1|=-|x-y_2|, x\in\Omega\}$ has a null Lebesgue measure?**

This fact would guarantee that $|\nabla d(x)|=1$ almost everywhere for $\Omega$ a Lipschitz domain. Is this true?

Comment: I think something stronger might hold. Does the discussion at the following link answer your question? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377613/distance-to-a-closed-set-is-this-result-known

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!!! I did not beleived that this is so general.