# For a closed Riemannian manifold $M$, must the set of points with non-unique closest points to a closed submanifold $S$ of $M$ be of 0 volume measure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, measure-theory

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed (compact without boundary) Riemannian manifold of finite dimension, with the volume measure $\mu:= \mu(E):=\int_{E}dvol_g \forall E \in \mathcal{B}(M),$ the Borel sigma algebra of $M.$

Let $S\subset M$ be a closed embedded submanifold, so $dim(S)<dim(M).$

Let $P_S:=\{x\in M: \text{minimizer of the distance from $x$ to $S$ is *not* unique}\}= \{x\in M: \exists x_1\ne x_2 \text{ such that } d(x,S)=d(x,x_1)=d(x,x_2)\}$

One can intuitive think that $P_S$ is 'small' in *some sense* (to be made precise soon). However, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3401294/is-the-set-where-there-is-a-unique-distance-minimizer-to-a-submanifold-open) and the [answer provided there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3401894/6920) show that the complement of $P_S$ may *not* be open. Next one can ask if $P_S$ has $\mu$-measure zero, at least when $S$ is "nice" enough (Sorry for being vague here, but that's because I don't know what sufficient conditions on $S$ will be necessary...).

**My questions are:**

1. For $M, S$ as above, is $\mu(P_S)=0$ always?
2. If the answer is negative, is $\mu(P_S)=0$ under certain conditions on $(g,S)?$
3. Is the answer positive/negative when $M$ is non-compact?

Related questions: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299054/distance-function-to-omega-subset-mathbbrn-differentiable-at-y-notin-omeg).

Comment: When you say "minimizer of the distance" are you talking about shortest paths between $x$ and the set $S$?

Comment: @RyanBudney: I edited the question, what I meant is that there are at least two points in $S$ realizing the distance from $s$ to $S, i.e.:$

$P_S:=\{x\in M: \exists x_1\ne x_2 \text{ such that } d(x,S)=d(x,x_1)=d(x,x_2)\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answers:

1. yes
2. does not apply, see 1.
3. I did not think sufficiently about it in order to make a precise statement, but I would guess, the answer is positive as well, probably with the same proof as for 1. The answer is certainly affirmative, if $S$ is compact and $M$ is complete. I have concerns, if $M$ is not complete.

A possibility to prove (or to sketch a proof of) answer 1 is to use the theory of the cut locus. This is worked out in all detail in the case that $S$ is a point (see e.g. Takashi Sakai, Riemannian Geometry, Chapter III, Section 4), but the relevant statements still hold for general closed embedded submanifold.
Consider the normal exponential map $\exp^S$ whose domain is the normal bundle of $S$ in $M$ and whose target is $M$. Consider the set $\mathcal{I}_S$ of all vectors $X$ in the normal bundle such that $[0,1]\to M$, $t\mapsto \gamma_X(t):=\exp^S (t X)$ is a unique length minimizing geodesic without focal points. Let $\mathcal{C}_S$ be the boundary of $\mathcal{I}_S$ in the normal bundel of $S$ in $M$. This set is called the tangential cut locus of $S$ in $M$. It requires a bit of work to see that $\mathcal{C}_S$ has zero measure in this normal bundle.

The set you are interested in is a subset of $\exp^S(\mathcal{C}_S)$.
As $\exp^S$ is absolutely continuous, it maps zero sets to zero sets.